# SQL - Group Results on Same Row

Tags: sql-server

So I've got data like so

```
id    type    date
1      1      2015-02-04
2      1      2015-02-04
3      2      2015-02-04
4      1      2015-02-05
5      2      2015-02-06
```

And I want a result like so

```
countForType1    countForType2      dow
      2               1           Wednesday
      1               0           Thursday
      0               1            Friday
etc...
```

I'm trying use the `OVER(PARTITION` but I think I'm using it incorrectly, or possibly, I need to use something else. Here is my current query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(seatType) OVER(PARTITION BY seatType) AS Counts,
    CASE DATEPART(DW,testDate)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Saturday'
    END dow
FROM tst_Tests
WHERE roomid = 1
GROUP BY DATEPART(DW,testDate), seatType
```

I'm not sure how to create a second column counting by an individual seat types.
I'm thinking I could just put two select statements inside the select statement, but that seems inefficient. I feel like there is a function for this I am using incorrectly or not at all.

EDIT: I made the example data match actual dates and numbers of what would be returned.

Comment: Can you give some example data and the result you'd expect from it? It's a little difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve without it. Your current query outputs different columns from those shown in your 'I want a result like so' section?

Comment: You can also write: case datepart(dw,testDate) when 1 then 'Sunday' when 2 then 'Monday'...

Comment: error thanks. @Elliveny Hopefully my sample data makes more sense. Trying to count the number of rows for each type, grouped by day of week. My current query counts them correctly, but I get two rows for each seatType. I want those counts for each type on the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Conditional Aggergate` instead of `window function`

```
SELECT Count(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN 1 END) AS countForType1,
       Count(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN 1 END) AS countForType2,
       CASE
         WHEN Datepart(DW, date) = 1 THEN 'Sunday'
         WHEN Datepart(DW, date) = 2 THEN 'Monday'
         WHEN Datepart(DW, date) = 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
         WHEN Datepart(DW, date) = 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
         WHEN Datepart(DW, date) = 5 THEN 'Thursday'
         WHEN Datepart(DW, date) = 6 THEN 'Friday'
         WHEN Datepart(DW, date) = 7 THEN 'Saturday'
       END        dow
FROM   Yoursampletable
GROUP  BY Datepart(DW, date)
```

Comment: wtf. I thought I tried putting a case in the count. My syntax must have been incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
DECLARE @Example TABLE ([Id] int, [type] int, [testDate] date)

INSERT INTO @Example ([Id], [type], [testDate])
SELECT 1,1,'2015-02-04' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,'2015-02-04' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,2,'2015-02-04' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,1,'2015-02-05' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,2,'2015-02-06'

;with rowsWithDayName as (
  select *, 
      CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW,testDate) = 1 THEN 'Sunday'
      WHEN DATEPART(DW,testDate) = 2 THEN 'Monday'
      WHEN DATEPART(DW,testDate) = 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
      WHEN DATEPART(DW,testDate) = 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
      WHEN DATEPART(DW,testDate) = 5 THEN 'Thursday'
      WHEN DATEPART(DW,testDate) = 6 THEN 'Friday'
      WHEN DATEPART(DW,testDate) = 7 THEN 'Saturday'
  END as [DayName]
  from @Example
)
select 
SUM(CASE WHEN [type]=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as countForType1
, SUM(CASE WHEN [type]=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as countForType2
, [DayName]
FROM rowsWithDayName
group by [DayName]
```